# Evaluating Arithmetic Expression Using Recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion, calculator

Here's an algorithm for evaluating an arithmetic expression using **recursion**:

- Find operand1
- t1 = Eval(operand1)
- Find operand2
- t2 = Eval(operand2)
- Apply operator on t1 and t2

Assumptions:

- each operand is between two operators
- there are only binary operations
- for each operation, there are parentheses (including outermost parentheses)

Input:

- array of tokens representing an arithmetic expression
- num_tokens is the number of tokens

Sample array of tokens: {"(", "9", "+", "(", "50", "-", "25", ")", ")"}

I tried to implement the algorithm but my program doesn't run (exit status -1 is the only message I get). Why is that happening?

```
int apply(char op, int a, int b) {
       if (op == '+'){
        printf("%d %c %d\n", a,op,b);
        return a + b;
       }
       else if (op == '-'){
        printf("%d %c %d\n", a,op,b);
        return a - b;
       }
       else if(op == '/'){
        printf("%d %c %d\n", a,op,b);
        return a / b;
       }
       else if(op == '*'){
        printf("%d %c %d\n", a,op,b);
        return a * b;
       }
}   

int eval_tokens(char** expression, int num_tokens)
{
  // implement me
    int index;
    int opIndex = find_operator(expression, num_tokens); //find index of operator
    int count1=0,count2=0,term1,term2,i,j;

    if(*expression[0] == '(')
      i = 1;
    else
      i = 0;

    while(i <= opIndex){
        i++;
        count1++;
    }

    term1 = eval_tokens(expression+1,count1);

    j = opIndex+1;
    while(j < num_tokens){
      count2++;
      j++;
    }

  term2 = eval_tokens(expression+opIndex+1,count2); //expression+opIndex+1 points to index after opIndex
  return apply(*expression[opIndex], term1, term2);
}

int main(void) {
    char*expression[] = {"(", "(", "5", "+", "3", ")", "-", "(", "2", "+", "1", ")", ")"};
    printf("result = %d\n", eval_tokens(expression, 13));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `**expression` serves as stack (queue actually). If it is infix on solely binary operators, the order is.. (1) take LHS operand from expression "stack" using a recursive call, (2) take the operand from stack, (3) take RHS operand from stack and evaluate then.

Comment: Well, the main problem with your program is that it's missing a `main` function.

Comment: @melpomene I did have a main function while testing. I'll add it to my question.

Comment: @StephanLechner How do I "take" from the expression "stack"?

Comment: @StephanLechner I tried using `term1 = infix_eval_tokens(expression+1,count1);` to take the left operand and `term2 = infix_eval_tokens(expression+opIndex+1,count2);` to take the right operand but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "Doesn't run" may be factually correct, but surely you can add something about what happens instead.

Comment: @usr2564301 the only thing that appears is "exit status -1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `str` (or `expression`) as stack from which you can take items off, I'd make these arguments "modifyable" in the recursive function. Therefore, you could introduce a second function `int eval_tokens_recursive(char*** expression, int *num_tokens)`, which has one more level of indirection and may actually "take items from the stack" by altering the arguments' values.

The code could look as follows. Hope it helps.

```
int eval_tokens_recursive(char*** expression, int *num_tokens) {

    char *token = **expression;
    if (*num_tokens == 0) {
        printf("expecting more tokens.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (*token == '(') { // begin of expression?
        (*expression)++;  // skip opening brace
        (*num_tokens)--;

        // lhs
        int lhs = eval_tokens_recursive(expression, num_tokens);

        // operand
        char operand = ***expression;
        (*expression)++;
        (*num_tokens)--;

        // rhs
        int rhs = eval_tokens_recursive(expression, num_tokens);

        (*expression)++;  // skip closing brace
        (*num_tokens)--;

        switch (operand) {
            case '+':
                return lhs + rhs;
            case '-':
                return lhs - rhs;
            case '*':
                return lhs * rhs;
            case '/':
                return lhs / rhs;
            default:
                return 0;
        }

    } else { // not an expression; must be a numeric token
        int operand;
        if (sscanf(token, "%2d", &operand) != 1) {
            printf("expecting numeric value; cannot parse %s.\n", token);
            exit(1);
        }
        (*expression)++;
        (*num_tokens)--;
        return operand;
    }

}

int eval_tokens(char** expression, int num_tokens) {
    return eval_tokens_recursive(&expression, &num_tokens);
}

int main() {

    char *expressions[] = {"(", "9", "+", "(", "50", "-", "25", ")", ")"};

    int result = eval_tokens(expressions, 9);

    printf("result: %d\n", result);

}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it possible for the same thing to be accomplished without a helper function? If so, would there be any significant differences in code length or the complexity of the statements within the function?

Comment: I don't think so, because I see no way of how to pass back how many items had been processed. Concerning code length/complexity, introducing one helper function will not count in any significant way.